# trouble running simple aditi scheduler tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to follow simple Aditi Scheduler tutorial but I am getting error. Here is my code.

What am I doing wrong?

> Error:  The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a
>   non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal
>   character among the padding characters.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ScheduledSMS()
{

    var tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxmyid";
    var secretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxmykey";


    var scheduledTasks = new ScheduledTasks(tenantId, secretKey);

    // create a task
    var task = new TaskModel
    {
        Name = "My first Scheduler job",
        JobType = JobType.Webhook,

        // use predefined CommonCronExpressions or build your own CRON expressions here http://cronmaker.com/
        CronExpression = CommonCronExpressions.EveryMinute,

        // use builders to set job properties for webhooks and azure queue 
        Params = ParamBuilderFactory
                    .WebHookBuilder("http://localhost:1901/SMS/SendText")
                    .Build()
    };

    var operationId = scheduledTasks.CreateTask(task);   <------ Error happens here..

    // all operations in the api follow fire and forget approach, once an operation like create/update/delete
    // is requested it returns an operationId(Guid) which can be used to fetch the operation status

    // operation status can be fetched in two ways:

    // method 1: (without polling) returns the status without polling
    var operationStatus = scheduledTasks.GetOperationStatus(operationId);

    // method 2: (with polling) polls until the operation status changes to success/error or a timeout occurs 
    // var operationStatus = scheduledTasks.GetOperationStatus(operationId, true);

    // get the task
    TaskModel newTask = null;
    if (operationStatus.Status == StatusCode.Success)
    {
        dynamic resultData = operationStatus.Data;
        var newTaskId = resultData["Id"];
        newTask = scheduledTasks.GetTask(Guid.Parse(newTaskId));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with the "localhost" in the url you pass to the WebHookBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

This is a couple months old, but I had this same problem until I realized I had the tenantId and secretKey reversed (stupid, but easy mistake). Once I swapped them it worked fine.